# Fire Storage Exception ([firebase_storage/unauthorized] User is not authorized to perform the desired action.) (my rule is allow read/write)

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, flutter-android

I am trying to get images from firebase firestore, while trying to get image download url there is this exception :

W/StorageUtil(10206): no auth token for request

*(similar questions with this error not solve the problem)*

Although my security rules allow read and write I getting this error still.

Any ideas what is the problem with this?

Code for getting image url :

```
  static Future<dynamic> loadImage(BuildContext context, String image) async {
    return await FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(image).getDownloadURL();
  }
```

Calling this loadImage function :

```
  Future<Widget> getImage(BuildContext context, String imgName) async {
   Image image;
    await FireStorageService.loadImage(context, imgName).then((value) {
    print(value);
    image = Image.network(value.toString(), fit: BoxFit.scaleDown);
    return image;
   });
  }
```

Calling this getImage function :

```
child: FutureBuilder(
future: getImage(context, "/images/test1.jpg"),
...
)
```

My firebase storage rules :

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
match /images/{imageId} {
  allow read,write;
}
}
```

Storage Rules ss:

[image]

My firebase store currently :
[image: My firebase store currently]

Comment: Can you provide the screenshot of your Rules section too?

Comment: I just added @Akif

Answer (score 6):

- Navigate to Firebase console
- In Sidebar under Develop open Storage
- Open Rules tab replace the rule on your console with the rule below:

  ```
   rules_version = '2';

   service firebase.storage {

     match /b/{bucket}/o {

       match /{allPaths=**} {

         allow read, write

       }

     }

   }
  ```

And Publish
Done

Answer (score 3):

**(2022):** Recently, I solved with following the Firestore basic security rules (for authenticated user):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

You can see this in their website: https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=1#cloud-storage_1

I do not suggest that using allow read, write; directly. If your application has a authentication, then you need to check if auth is null or not.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by changing the rules.

Go to Firebase project>Storage>Rules.

By default, you are not allowed to upload on Firebase so you have to change that.

- Default rules

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

Change `allow read, write: if false;` to `allow read, write;`

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Settings -> App Check -> Products
Change the Storage from Enforce -> Unenforced
[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

This works for me by changing the rules in firebase.

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write
    }
  }
}
```